# Reading tabular data with python

Tags: python, csv

I have a bunch of text files with tabular data. It looks like this:

```
 1. BRISTOL CITY             42  16  4  1  43  13   8  7  6  23  27   59
 2. Plymouth Argyle          42  18  3  0  47   6   5  4 12  14  23   53
 3. Swansea City             42  13  6  2  46  14   9  3  9  32  31   53
 4. Brighton & Hove Albion   42  15  3  3  39  13   5  8  8  13  21   51
 5. Luton Town               42  14  4  3  47  18   7  3 11  21  31   49
 6. Millwall                 42   9 10  2  27  13   5  8  8  18  27   46
 7. Portsmouth               42  10  5  6  34  20   9  3  9  24  32   46
 8. Northampton              42  13  6  2  40  17   4  5 12  14  27   45
 9. Swindon Town             42  14  4  3  41  17   3  7 11  21  39   45
10. Watford                  42  10  6  5  35  23   7  4 10  22  31   44
11. Queen's Park Rangers     42  10  4  7  34  24   6  6  9  20  25   42
12. Charlton Athletic        42  11  6  4  33  14   3  8 10  22  37   42
13. Bristol Rovers           42   7  9  5  25  19   6  7  8  10  17   42
14. Brentford                42   9  4  8  27  23   4  8  9  14  28   38
15. Southend United          42  10  6  5  35  18   2  7 12  14  36   37
16. Gillingham               42  13  4  4  38  18   2  3 16  13  41   37
17. Merthyr Town             42  10  4  7  27  17   1 10 10  12  31   36
18. Norwich City             42   8  7  6  29  26   5  3 13  22  45   36
19. Reading                  42   9  8  4  24  15   1  6 14  12  40   34
20. Exeter City              42  10  4  7  27  18   3  3 15  20  66   33
```

It's very regular, but there's no standard separator and the column widths are not standard from table to table (even within the same files). (Spaces alone aren't a sufficient delimiter, as many of the names contain spaces and in some places, columns are separated by only a single space.)

I want to parse this into Python objects, but it's not really clear what the best way to do that is. Is there a way to use the CSV module to parse it? Do I need to use regex? Has someone written an awesome python library for parsing tabular text files?

Comment: what happens when you try to use the `csv` module?  Is it not working?

Comment: Is '\t' the delimiter?

Comment: You could use regex to match each element per line.

Comment: Is the second column the only one that can contain letters and spaces? Or can other columns be non-numeric as well? Can the second column contain numbers? A couple more complicated sample rows might be useful.

Comment: I've added some more complicated data rows here. Except for the name, the columns contain only numbers. When I use the CSV module, I have to set a delimiter; one space breaks up the names and two spaces occasionally grafts a number onto the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a working regex. [Look it up here for explanation/modifying.](http://regex101.com/r/uW8nQ2)

The name of the line (like Accrington) is extracted with `[\D]+?`. That means "Take as much non-digits as you need to fit in the line". (`+?` - non greedy) So you can get alphabetical letters and (minimal) whitespace and that would be the name of your line...

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"^(\d+.)\s*([\D]+?)" + r"\s+(\d+)"*12 + r"\s*$")
```

**Test**

```
match = pattern.match("7. Accrington               22   5  3  3  26  17   1  5  5  22  31   20")
print match.groups()
Out[133]: 
('7.',
 'Accrington',
 '22',
 '5',
 '3',
 '3',
 '26',
 '17',
 '1',
 '5',
 '5',
 '22',
 '31',
 '20')

match2 = pattern.match("91. Accrington Bay              22   5  3  3  26  17   1  5  5  22  31   20")
print match2
Out[134]: 
('91.',
 'Accrington Bay',
 '22',
 '5',
 '3',
 '3',
 '26',
 '17',
 '1',
 '5',
 '5',
 '22',
 '31',
 '20')
```

Comment: Yep, this works, and is better than the regex I was working on, thanks! I was hoping there's a non-regex way to do it, but I'll probably just use this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use regular expressions.

You can use the `split()` method (apart of Python's included `re` module) to split the data at every sequence of consecutive whitespace.

```
import re

data = '7. Accrington               22   5  3  3  26  17   1  5  5  22  31   20'
for line in re.split('\n+', data):
    print(re.split('\s+', line))
```

which will print the following:

```
['7.', 'Accrington', '22', '5', '3', '3', '26', '17', '1', '5', '5', '22', '31', '20']
```

Note that the above example also handles multiple lines of data (assuming such lines are separated by consecutive newlines).

Comment: If the OP's just splitting on consecutive whitespace, then there's no need for `re`: just `line.split()` will do it.  But the OP would need to do at least a little more work, because the name part may contain multiple words.  If the final terms are all numeric, though, he could recombine.

Comment: Good point; I have modified my example to only split at sequences of two or more whitespace characters.

Comment: That won't do it either: the OP warned that sometimes columns are only separated by a single space. :^)

Answer (score 0):

`skipinitialspace` is what you need to use the `csv` module for this one.

```
$ cat << EOF > /tmp/sample.csv
> 7. Accrington               22   5  3  3  26  17   1  5  5  22  31   20
> 7. Accrington               22   5  3  3  26  17   1  5  5  22  31   20
> 8. Accrington               22   5  3  3  26  17   1  5  5  22  31   22
> 7. Accrington               22   5  3  3  26  17   1  5  5  22  31   21
> EOF
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import csv
>>> reader = csv.reader(open('/tmp/sample.csv'), skipinitialspace=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter=' ')
>>> for row in reader: 
...     print row
... 
['7.', 'Accrington', '22', '5', '3', '3', '26', '17', '1', '5', '5', '22', '31', '20']
['7.', 'Accrington', '22', '5', '3', '3', '26', '17', '1', '5', '5', '22', '31', '20']
['8.', 'Accrington', '22', '5', '3', '3', '26', '17', '1', '5', '5', '22', '31', '22']
['7.', 'Accrington', '22', '5', '3', '3', '26', '17', '1', '5', '5', '22', '31', '21']
```

Don't forget you can unpack the results for each row, like so:

```
>>> for pk, name, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l in reader:
```

Comment: According to OP, many of the names (I assume this means the second field) contain spaces.